# how to take entire line as input to a string variable after taking a double as input?

Tags: c++, string

aim: write a program in c++

1.Declare  variables: one of type double, and one of type String.

2.Print the sum of  your double variable to a scale of one decimal place on a new line.

3.Concatenate  with the string you read as input and print the result on a new line.
 (complete this program )

```
 int main()
 {

double d = 4.0;
string s = "hello and welcome ";

//write ur code here
//  double variable
//string variable
//i/p double from user
// i/p string from user
// print sum of double
// print concatenated string
```

}

sample i/p=---
 4.0
umang mahant!

sample o/p----
8.0
hello and welcome umang mahant!

```
 //this is my code but it isnt taking the line as input i really dont know why?
   #include <iostream>
   #include <iomanip>
   #include <limits>

   using namespace std;

   int main() {
   double d = 4.0;
   string s = "hello and welcome ";
   double b;
   string s2;
   cin>>b;
   getline(cin, s2, '\n');
   cout<<d+b<<"\n";
   cout<<s<<s2<<"\n";
   }
```

Comment: 1) How would expect your code to output `hello and welcome` if that string isn't present in the code, nor in the sample input. 2) Can't you define what do you mean by _isn't taking the line as input_? Since it [is taking whole line as an input](http://ideone.com/nN6W2Q).

Comment: @Umang Mahant .Hi from pune .printing them together is not concatenating ! You need to use inbuilt functions for that :) and for taking input just change the getline function as suggested by A Busy Programmer

Comment: @minigeek i am a beginner... i just need to print them together.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius sorry for that i have made the corrections . also i mean "isnt taking the input" means .....string s2;
  cin>>b;
  getline(cin, s2, '\n');
cout<<s2; //this DOESNT PRINT THE LINE WHICH I HAVE GIVEN AS INPUT...

Comment: guys pls reff. this  https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-data-types  and help me solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change s to

```
s = "hello and welcome"
```

Then have a look at following code

```
#include <strtk.hpp>

double sum = d + b ; // adding doubles 

std::string sum_as_string = strtk::type_to_string<double>(sum); //converted sum to string

std::string final_string = sum_as_string + s2 + s;//concatenate your input string to sum string  and s string
```

Now print the final_string.

(You were not concatenating strings in real , printing them together is not a solution ! )
After `getline(cin, s2)` insert this code and delete two cout statements then at last write

```
 cout<<final_string<<"\n";
```

If you dont want to concatenate strings in real then you can just correct input function `getline`.

**Answer to your hackerrank challenge**

```
int p;
double q;
string s2,result;

// Declare second integer, double, and String variables.

// Read and save an integer, double, and String to your variables.
cin>>p;
cin>>q;
getline(cin >> ws ,s2);

// Note: If you have trouble reading the entire string, please go back and review the Tutorial closely.

// Print the sum of both integer variables on a new line.
cout<<p+i<<"\n";


// Print the sum of the double variables on a new line.
std::cout << std::fixed;
std::cout << std::setprecision(1);
cout<<q+d<<"\n";
// Concatenate and print the String variables on a new line
result = s + s2;
cout<<result<<"\n";
```

Comment: please go to this link.   https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-data-types      as i cannot include a header flie in this challange can we have another method to solve it?

Comment: And it is hackerrank string only In challenge not hello and welcome

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the code you've posted below the sample input and output is the one you're asking about.

The problem lies in your getline() function. Why do you have 3 arguments in this function? It produces an error. You should change your getline() statement to:

```
    getline(cin, s2);
```

This eliminates the error and your code works as it should.